# rspec: multiple expectations about expected method arguments

Tags: rspec

Is there a way to get a handle on the arguments passed to the test subject, and then test multiple distinct expectations on the arguments?  Something like this:

```rb
expect(foo).to receive(:bar)

subject.method_under_test

expect(args_passed_to_foo).to be hash_including(key1: "some value")
expect(args_passed_to_foo).to be hash_including(key2: /some regexp/)
expect(args_passed_to_foo.keys).not_to include(:key3)
expect(some_method(args_passed_to_foo[:key4])).to be > SOME_CONST
```

The only way that I know to sort of do the above is something like:

```rb
expect(foo).to receive(:bar).with(
  # ........
)

subject.method_under_test
```

but that can't really handle the most complex cases, and it also is terribly unwieldly, and you are testing many things with one `expect`, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Any reason you aren’t just saying `to eq(some_expected_hash)`? I would personally start there as a baseline for your tests and then if there’s edge cases that you need to test about individual keys, you can start to one by one test individual keys. I feel like doing anything else starts causing you to write inverse tests which are arguably worse than testing multiple things. (An inverse test being one of infinity keys that a hash doesn’t have.)

Comment: I would also say that some people go overboard about testing “one” thing. Like if I were writing a request spec, it’s pointless to run three tests so that I can test the response code, the content type, and the body, just because they’re separate things that can be tested. I typically choose to test “one” thing, being the “response”. When you test your one thing like this, your tests run faster, and the intention can at times be more clear. At the end of the day, testing one thing is important mostly for readability. If it reads well, and tests the scenarios that you need tested, great!

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Nate.  In my particular case, I am testing the properties of a couple of large strings being sent as arguments to a method.  I can certainly write a gargantuan Regexp, but it would be brutal to write and brutal to read.  I'd rather have a series of expect-ations which very clearly convey the test intentions.  These expectations might simply check for substring presence, but they might also have slightly more complicated regexp matching.

Comment: I suppose what I could do is have a separate class generate the large string as output, then I would be able to test the output much more simply with rspec.

Comment: I’m not sure what any of the code looks like, but that sounds like a nice way to thin out the method that’s generating the hash. I’m not sure what this Hash is, but it may make sense to make a whole class out of it, have each key be a method, and then if you really need a Hash as output, you could make a `to_h` method which loops through an array of methods names to include in the output Hash. Of course, if it’s not actually complicated, that may be over-engineering.

Comment: Just to clarify the context a little: The subject under test is a mailer which builds up a subject, body, etc. given some arguments, and then calls the actual mailing code (which contacts SMTP, etc.).  So I'm just testing that the subject and body and so on have certain specific bits in them, like a user's name ("Hello First Last!"), and some details in the body.  But, indeed, it's looking like splitting out the body generation to its own class would be a good idea, as then it can have a public output method, and I can have independent tests for that.  Thanks for the discussion, it has helped.

Comment: I think the approach you just mentioned makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the way to get a handle on the arguments passed to a test subject is:

```rb
before do
  allow(foo).to receive(:bar)
end

it 'does something' do
  subject.method_under_test

  expect(foo).to have_received(:bar) do |args_passed_to_foo|
    expect(args_passed_to_foo).to be hash_including(key1: "some value")
    expect(args_passed_to_foo).to be hash_including(key2: /some regexp/)
    expect(args_passed_to_foo.keys).not_to include(:key3)
    expect(some_method(args_passed_to_foo[:key4])).to be > SOME_CONST    
  end
end
```

RSpec allows you to pass a block after a `have_received` expectation. The block will be yielded the arguments passed to the actual call.

Comment: Very interesting.  This is good information.  Unfortunately, I went with the separate class solution that I described in the comment thread above, but what you've shared is good to know.  Thanks.